# ASP.NET events don't run on Internet Explorer 10?

Tags: asp.net, event-handling, internet-explorer-10

It seems to happen on events I'm attaching through code and not to the events bound to the element in the aspx file. The events simply don't run, nothing happens.

It's strange because IE10 is the only browser which has this problem, all of the other ones work perfectly fine.

Any idea what's causing this?

EDIT:
Forgot to mention this, but changing the browser standards doesn't work. Only changing the Browser mode

Comment: I think you're confusing "Asp.Net events" with client side javascript events. Otherwise the browser has **nothing** to do with server side events firing. Check to see if you have script errors

Comment: What event? What code? How can we know if we see no code?

Comment: Just a simple onindexchanged event from a dropdownbox doesn't function. And I'm definitely not talking about clientside scripts, no script errors are there. This is definitely a browser problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a problem with older versions of browser definition files for the .NET framework that cause IE10 not to be recognized as a JavaScript capable browser, changing the code it emits to the browser in question and often breaking a lot of the postback handling related to the _doPostback function.  You can read more information about that on [this blog entry from Scott Hanselman](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/BugAndFixASPNETFailsToDetectIE10CausingDoPostBackIsUndefinedJavaScriptErrorOrMaintainFF5ScrollbarPosition.aspx).

There is a hotfix available ([KB 2600088](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2600088)) from Microsoft to address this for .NET 4.0. If you're looking for 2.0, there are separate articles for Windows 7 and Server 2008 R2 ([KB 2608565](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2600088)) and older operating systems ([KB 2600100](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2600100)).

I should mention that I didn't have a great deal of success with installing the 4.0 package to Server 2003, but I'm looking into what might have caused that. It doesn't look like the installer actually updated the required browser definition files. If you're experiencing this problem as well, the files that need to be updated are available for direct download under the "SITE-ONLY FIXES" section of the blog entry linked above (or to save you some time, [here](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/content/binary/App_BrowsersUpdate.zip)).

If you need a temporary fix, you can emit an HTTP header in your IIS configuration for the header "[X-UA-Compatible](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms533876%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)" with value set to "IE=9".

Comment: Hi there, this sounds like a possible fix. I have the problem with a SharePoint 2010 environment running .NET 3.5 and Server 2008 R2. Will check out the blog entry. I think the meta tag is already set on IE 8.